# Faster deletion of values in hash of arrays

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the following hash:

```
new_hash = {
  [1] => [2, 3, 4, 7, 8 ],
  [2] => [3, 5],
  [3] => [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [4] => [],
}
```

I want to select the key that has the largest number of elements, i.e. the third key.

I have tried:

```
selected_user = new_hash.max_by{|k,v| v.length}.first
```

Upon finding the key which contains the largest number of elements, I then would like to delete the values from all the other elements. The result I want is:

```
new_hash = {
  [1] => [2, 3, 4],
  [2] => [3],
  [3] => [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [4] => [],
}
```

I've tried using array to delete all duplicated items by pushing the values into an array, and then deleting all the elements in a 2D array.

```
for a in 0..new_arr.length-1
    new_arr[a] = new_arr[a] - newer_arr
end
```

This is workable, however the speed for large hashes is very low. How can I improve the speed of this operation?

Answer (score 1):

```
new_hash = { [1] => [2, 3, 4, 7, 8 ], [2] => [3, 5], [3] => [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [4] => [], }

selected_user = new_hash.max_by{|k,v| v.length}.first

selected_values = new_hash[selected_user]

new_hash.each do |k, v|
  next if k == selected_user
  new_hash[k] = v - selected_values
end

puts new_hash
```

When run:

```
{[1]=>[2, 3, 4], [2]=>[3], [3]=>[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [4]=>[]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
selected_user_key = new_hash.max_by{|k,v| v.length}.first    

# I suggest to use dup to not alter the original new_hash
return_hash = new_hash.dup

# Step 1 - remove the element from the hash
elements_of_selected_user = return_hash.delete(selected_user_key)

# Step 2 - remove the items that are in elements_of_selected_user
return_hash = Hash[return_hash.map{|k,v| [k, v - elements_of_selected_user]}]

# Step 3 - add the element back to the hash
return_hash[selected_user_key] = elements_of_selected_user
```

This works because in Ruby you can do Array operations such as `-`:

```
[1,2,3] - [2] == [1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
key, value = new_hash.max_by { |_,a| a.size }
new_hash.merge(new_hash) { |_,v| v - value }.update(key=>value)
  #=> {[1]=>[2, 3, 4], [2]=>[3], [3]=>[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [4]=>[]}
```

This uses the form of [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employs the block

```
{ |_,v| v - value }
```

to determine the value of each key in the merged hash.

If two keys have the same size arrays as their values, the result will of course depend on the ordering of the keys (Ruby v1.9+).

Answer (score 0):

There is a good possibility that it's the Arrays rather than the Hashes that slow you down...

When you use `[1,2,3]  - [1,2]`, you are creating a third array, and this creation of more and more objects, as you iterate through the Hash, invokes memory allocations which slow you down.

If you know that all the members of an Array are unique, I would recommend that you use Sets instead of Arrays, leveraging the[Set#subtract](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-subtract) method...

```
require 'set'
new_hash = {
  [1] => [2, 3, 4, 7, 8 ].to_set,
  [2] => [3, 5].to_set,
  [3] => [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].to_set,
  [4] => [].to_set,
}

selected_user = new_hash.max_by{|k,v| v.length}.first
values = new_hash[selected_user]
new_hash.each {|k, v| v.subtract values unless k == selected_user}
```

The creation of the Set objects is slightly slower because of the difference in the memory allocation and object management, but since you are not creating new objects using this process, it should be slightly more efficient - especially for large persistent data structures.

P.S.

Is there a reason why you use Arrays in the user id key? Hash keys are frozen and cannot be changed, so I don't see the added value in using Arrays (which would slow you down compared with a FixNum).

why not use:

```
require 'set'
new_hash = {
  1 => [2, 3, 4, 7, 8 ].to_set,
  2 => [3, 5].to_set,
  3 => [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].to_set,
  4 => [].to_set,
}
```